# WordPress MultiSite - Block Access to Subfolder on Server for All But One Site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

The WordPress installation has several sites/domains.  Separate from the WordPress installation is an HTML site in a subfolder on the server.  I only want one of the domains to be able to access this folder, the other domains should not be able to see the folder.  I also need to block specific files, not in the same folder but along side it (all in public_html).

I have looked around and tried a few things, here is what I have at the moment, but it does not work, I get an internal server error when I use this:

```
SetEnvIf Referer mydomain\.com localreferer
<Location /myfolder>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=localreferer
</Location> 
<FilesMatch myfile.php>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=localreferer
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that involves `mod_rewrite` (place it in `.htaccess` file into root folder). It will forbid (403 code) access to any resource that located `myfolder` unless it is requested via `mydomain.com` (e.g. `http://mydomain.com/myfolder`).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^myfolder(/|/.*)?$ - [NC,F]
```

The rule below will do the same but for `/myfile.php` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^myfile\.php$ - [NC,F]
```

As to your original approach -- try this: `<FilesMatch "myfile\.php">`. [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch) works with regular expression and therefore may need to be declared in this way.